# setOnItemClickListener not updating with notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm using notifyDataSetChanged with my custom GridViewAdapter which updates the listView however when I click on something with my updated listView, the old links are still there. I have the following ClickListener in my onCreate method.

```
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SpiceList.class);
                intent.putExtra("INGREDIENTS_CALL", true);
                intent.putExtra("INGREDIENTS_SELECTED", position + 1);
                if (recipeCall) {
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPE_CALL", true);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
```

I've tried duplicating this inside the buttons that update the listView but this does not work. Any ideas for how I can best update my listener to reflect my changed listView?

Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the old links are still there"? The only thing from the callback you are using is the position - which is the position in your listview/adapterlist at that moment.

Comment: I mean that say my original listView was "Item 1, Item 2, Item 3". When I call my notifyDataSetChange() to change my adapter to "Item 1, Item 3", the listView displays "Item 1, Item 3" but when I click on Item 3, it registers as Item 2 because the clickListener did not update along with my listView.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but my question is: how can you tell? Based on the code that you shared the only piece of information you use from the listener is the position (which in your example would have been 1, because item3 is now the second in the list). Are you trying to use this position and get the item from another list (in your launched activity) that is not filtered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the way I was retrieving my SQL queries. I was making the position of my listener equal to the ID of the SQL entry I was retrieving. Therefore, even though my list changed, item 1 was still pulling SQL items with an ID of 1.

When I designed my queries in Android, I originally did not expect that I would run into this problem. However, now I've linked my SQL queries to the actual item ID and not the listener position. My new listener is now:

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SpiceList.class);
                intent.putExtra("INGREDIENTS_CALL", true);
                intent.putExtra("INGREDIENTS_SELECTED", Integer.parseInt(resultsID.get(position)));
                if (recipeCall) {
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPE_CALL", true);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understand your question but let me see if i can try. You are changing the listviews views when you click on one?

Are you deleting any element in the array or List you are using for your adapter? So you remove an item and then call notifyDataSetChange()? or you add an item to the array and call the notify method?

Comment: I'm filtering the ListView (through a SQL query) which is refreshing it. It may result in a different size array. It looks like this: `code`                (IngredientsListAdapter.add(results, null);
                IngredientsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();)